# Can we say that 'Limit' is an operator?

Tags: calculus, limits

Can we say that 'Limit' is an operator?

This idea has come to mind visualizing the fact that " '$\frac{d}{dx}$' is an operator and derivative of a function is defined by 'Limit'".

Comment: Well, the limit as $x$ *approaches something* is an operator, such as $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}$.

Comment: If that point of view helps, then why not?

Comment: In the aspect that limiting operation can assign a number to a map at a point, it behaves as an operator; but I think a more interesting question is to ask why people do not develop limit theory this way. I believe there must be some far-vision reason.

Answer (score 6):

Though limits can be thought as operators, as far as I know this is not a prevalent viewpoint in mathematics. I guess the following example partially explains it.

Consider the space $C(\Bbb{R}, \Bbb{C})$ of $\Bbb{C}$-valued continuous functons on $\Bbb{R}$. Then for each $a \in \Bbb{R}$, limit as $x\to a$ is simply the evaluation map $a \mapsto f(a)$, which is linear and multiplicative by limit laws.

Now if $\mathcal{C}$ is the space of continuous functions $f\in C(\Bbb{R},\Bbb{C})$ which converges as $x\to+\infty$, then the limit operator

$$f \mapsto \lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) \tag{*}$$

is also a well-defined multiplicative linear functional. Instead of thinking it as some exotic operator, we can enlarge $\Bbb{R}$ to $X = \Bbb{R}\cup\{+\infty\}$ so that $\mathcal{C} \simeq C(X, \Bbb{C})$ and (*) reduces to the evauation map at $+\infty$.

In this viewpoint, limit as oprator has rather simple structure since they are realized as evaluaton map on a bigger space.